# Symfony 3.4 Functional tests

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, functional-testing

I have been stuck for some time on an error to do my functional tests with symfony 3.4.

My app run a custom GuardAuthenticator for authenticate my users within CAS authentication. This is just for explain the context. In my tests, I don't want to use it, I want to use a specific authentication system.

I wrote functional tests. I started my test environment with the following :

```yaml
# app/config/config_test.yml
imports:
    - { resource: config_dev.yml }

framework:
    test: ~
    session:
        storage_id: session.storage.mock_file
        name: MOCKSESSION
    profiler:
        collect: false
```

According to the official Symfony doc, I extends symfony WebTestCase for set a specific authentication token for my tests [How to Simulate HTTP Authentication in a Functional Test](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/testing/http_authentication.html#creating-the-authentication-token)

```php
namespace Test\AppBunble\WebTestCase;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase as SfTestCase;

class WebTestCase extends SfTestCase
{
    /**
     *
     * {@inheritDoc}
     * @see \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase::setUp()
     */
    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->client = static::createClient();
        $this->container = $this->client->getContainer();
        $this->entityManager = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');

        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function logInAs($username)
    {
        $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->loadUserByUsername($username);
        
        $session = $this->client->getContainer()->get('session');
        $token = new PostAuthenticationGuardToken($user, 'main', $user->getRoles());
        $session->set('_security_main', serialize($token));
        
        $session->save();
        
        $cookie = new Cookie($session->getName(), $session->getId());
        $this->client->getCookieJar()->set($cookie);
    }
}
```

Finally, I wrote my (simple) test :

```php
namespace Tests\AppBundle\Controller;

use Tests\AppBundle\WebTestCase;

class DefaultControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function testIndex()
    {
        $this->logInAs('admin');
        $crawler = $this->client->request('GET', '/');
        $this->assertTrue($client->getResponse()->isSuccessful(), 'response status is 2xx');
    }
}
```

I ran phpunit :

```sh
$ ./vendor/bin/simple-phpunit 
PHPUnit 5.7.27 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Testing app Test Suite
<br />
<b>Error</b>: <font color="FF0000"><b>Internal script failure</b><br />
```

For debugging, I modified my test :

```php
    public function testIndex()
    {
        $this->logInAs('admin');
        //$crawler = $this->client->request('GET', '/');
        //$this->assertTrue($client->getResponse()->isSuccessful(), 'response status is 2xx');
    }
```

I ran phpunit :

```sh
 ./vendor/bin/simple-phpunit 
PHPUnit 5.7.27 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Testing app Test Suite
.                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 797 ms, Memory: 27.75MB

OK (1 test, 0 assertions)
```

After lots of tests I found when I call in my test :

```php
$this->client->request('GET', '/')
```

It crash.

**UPDATE : another test.**

If I ran this :

```php
    public function testIndex()
    {
        $this->logInAs('admin');
        $token = $this->client->getContainer()->get('security.token_storage');
        var_dump($token->getToken());

        //$crawler = $this->client->request('GET', '/');
        //$this->assertTrue($client->getResponse()->isSuccessful(), 'response status is 2xx');
    }
```

It return me `NULL`... no token.

**UPDATE 2**

I dove into the code to go back to the point where symfony stops. It's in the `doDispatch` method of `Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher` class.

It trigger the listeners on the `kernel.event' event. And when it trigger the listener named "Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Debug\TraceableFirewallListener" => "internal script failure".

**UPDATE 3**
If I compare dev.log (which represents log when I run app in browser), I have this log on a request :

```
[2020-10-23 13:55:56] request.INFO: Matched route "app_homepage". {"route":"app_homepage","route_parameters":{"_controller":"AppBundle\\Controller\\DefaultController::indexAction","_route":"app_homepage"},"request_uri":"http://localhost:8180/","method":"GET"} []
[2020-10-23 13:55:56] security.DEBUG: Read existing security token from the session. {"key":"_security_main","token_class":"Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Guard\\Token\\PostAuthenticationGuardToken"} []
[2020-10-23 13:55:56] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT [...]
[2020-10-23 13:55:56] security.DEBUG: User was reloaded from a user provider.  [...]
```

But when I run `$this->client->request('GET', '/')`, my test.log show :

```
[2020-10-23 13:55:56] request.INFO: Matched route "app_homepage". {"route":"app_homepage","route_parameters":{"_controller":"AppBundle\\Controller\\DefaultController::indexAction","_route":"app_homepage"},"request_uri":"http://localhost","method":"GET"} []
```

No trace from security.

**UPDATE 4 : another test**

I ran this test :

```
    public function testIndex()
    {
        $crawler = $this->client->request('GET', '/stackTest');
        $this->assertTrue($this->client->getResponse()->isSuccessful(), 'response status is 2xx');
    }
```

It's a page with this configuration in security.yml

```yaml
firewalls:
    stack:
        pattern: ^/stackTest
        security: false
```

... and the test works!

```
 ./vendor/bin/simple-phpunit 
PHPUnit 5.7.27 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Testing app Test Suite
.                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 1.08 seconds, Memory: 36.50MB

OK (1 test, 1 assertion)
```

Comment: Maybe you need to implement the interfaces Serializable and EquatableInterface as mentioned in this part of the docomuntation? https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_provider.html#understanding-how-users-are-refreshed-from-the-session

Comment: @Vyctorya, My User entity implement the interface Serializable. When I watch test.log, the only line I have when I call `$this->client->request('GET', '/')` is ```[2020-10-23 13:21:01] request.INFO: Matched route "app_homepage". {"route":"app_homepage","route_parameters":{"_controller":"AppBundle\\Controller\\DefaultController::indexAction","_route":"app_homepage"},"request_uri":"http://localhost/","method":"GET"} []```. It's weird as if symfony is stopping somewhere, hence the "internal servererror" message.

Comment: As you implementing `\Serializable`, it could be that not all the necessary properties serializing/unserializing properly, which used to compare if user changed.
Try to debug `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\AbstractToken::hasUserChanged()`. But that's weird that it fails with error, I guess problem somewhere else.

Comment: @vstelmakh, hasUserChanged method is not reached. I think the "internal script failure" stop the process before. Maybe, I do something wrong for the authentication for functional tests ? I am lost... I think the problem is somewhere else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found !

As said above, the authentication of my app is done via CAS. For testing, I want to simulate this authentication. So I created a FakeGuardAuthenticator which instead of interrogating the CAS server, simulates it and returns the credentials.

In my config_test.yml configuration file, I therefore have to override the guardAuthenticator by passing through an alias.

Which give :

```
# app/config/config_test.yml
imports:
    - { resource: config_dev.yml }
    - { resource: services_test.yml }
```

```yaml
# app/config/service_test.yml
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false

    app_cas.guard_authenticator:
        class : Tests\AppBundle\FakeGuardAuthenticator
        arguments:
          # [...]
        provider: cas
```

Thansk to @vstelmakh and @Vyctorya for taking time to respond to me.

Comment: Good to know that you found the solution. Don't forget to accept your own answer. This could help others to know that the issue solved. https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/